# Weird shading transparent texture for grass

Tags: particles

Im trying to make polygon grass using the addon images from plane to import a grass texture with transparent background and im using particles to place them all over a plane. When they are widely spread between each other the texture looks normal but if they are close they have some weird black shading/shadow. I upload a picture to show what i mean...[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could have something to do with your render settings. Try to increase the values under Light Paths -> Transparency.

Comment: Seems like that solved the problem, Thank you !